# Magento 2.4.1: Place order using stripe payment method through REST API

Tags: magento2, stripe

I am making the mobile app in andriod and IOS using Magento2 as backend. In our website we are using stripe payment method.
Now I am trying to place an order using stripe method.

I am using magento default API in order to place an order "http://XXXX.com/rest/V1/carts/36/order" (where 36 is my quote id). I checked many documents and they suggested to use following in body:

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
    "method": "stripe_payments",
        "additional_data" : {
        "cc_save" : false,
        "cc_stripejs_token" : "pm_card_visa:visa:4242"
        }
    }
}
```

By using above in body order is placed successfully and I got the order id in response. But now I am trying to make "cc_stripejs_token" from request received from app team. They have following information:

```
 card =     {
        brand = Visa;
        country = US;
        "cvc_check" = unchecked;
        "exp_month" = 8;
        "exp_year" = 2023;
        funding = credit;
        id = "card_1ImFqhGpA1zE4WUlvS12Hl9m";
        last4 = 4242;
        name = test;
        object = card;
    };
    "client_ip" = "132.154.98.207";
    created = 1619864099;
    id = "tok_1ImFqhGpA1zE4WUl3Eg9UFpA";
    livemode = 0;
    object = token;
    type = card;
    used = 0;
}
```

Now I am trying to make "cc_stripejs_token" by using this formula:

```
token.id + ':' + token.card.brand + ':' + token.card.last4
```

My body looks like

```
{
           "paymentMethod": {
            "method": "stripe_payments",
             "additional_data" : {
                "cc_save" : false,
                "cc_stripejs_token" : "tok_1ImFqhGpA1zE4WUl3Eg9UFpA:visa:4242"
             }
        }
   
}
```

But I am getting error "TypeError: Return value of
Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin::aroundPlace() must
implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface.

I also tried by placing order using stripe intent method.

```
       \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('MY SECRET KEY');
        $st_response = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
                    "card" => array(
                        "number" => "4242424242424242",
                        "exp_month" => 1,
                        "exp_year" => 2024,
                        "cvc" => "314"
                    )
        ));
       echo json_encode($st_response);         
       $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array('amount' => 1000, 'currency' => "eur", 'source' => $st_response['id']));
      //echo json_encode($charge); 
      $tokenCard = $st_response['id'] . ':' . $charge['payment_method_details']['card']['brand'] . ':' . $charge['payment_method_details']['card']['last4'];
```

Payment is successful as I can see entries in Stripe dashboard but when trying to place an order using $tokenCard then it again shows error.

Please help me how can I place an order.

Comment: Hello Ankita have you find out any solution I am also facing the same kind of issue on place order API with stripe payment method

Answer (score 0):

May you please follow this link, seems like they have similar problem and solution.
This link can help you also

[Order beforeSave plugin throws TypeError](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283724/order-beforesave-plugin-throws-typeerror)

Thanks,
Vibhore

Comment: Thanks Vibhore, but issue is not with order function. Issue is with "cc_stripejs_token". If I am passing "cc_stripejs_token" : "pm_card_visa:visa:4242" then order is placed successfully. I want how I get "cc_stripejs_token" from cards used by user?

Answer (score 0):

`cc_stripejs_token` is supposed to be a payment method (`pm_` prefix), not a token (`tok_` prefix).

Here are the docs for creating a payment method using stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method

For example:

```
const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: 'card',
  card: cardElement,
});

const cc_stripejs_token = paymentMethod.id;
```

It turns out that the other parts separated by `:` don't matter since in the PHP code, they just throw those away.

Answer (score 0):

- if you want to reuse/charge for already stored card in stripe
- open table 'sales_order_payment'
- find "additional_information" column
- there will be data like "token":"pm_1Ls3dsdf2Xr4V1X3Sv6"
- in below code paste it at against 'cc_stripejs_token'

or use $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation("token") to fetch 'cc_stripejs_token' from original order

**if you are using new stripe card:**

```
<?php
$domainUrl = 'https://yourdomain.com/';
$username = "adminUsername";
$password = "adminPassword";
$customerEmail = "customer@gmail.com";
$customerPassword = "cutomerPassword";
$productSku = 'ProductSku';
$apiKey = 'sk_test_351LTF3dfGkKu23hh6pmhXr1sE4IMZawsdreRe'; //stripe secret key

function getAdminToken() // admin token to get access of admin data
{
    global $domainUrl;
    global $username;
    global $password;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token';
    $data = [
        "username" => $username,
        "password" => $password
    ];
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Got token $response\n"."<br>";
    return $response;
}
function getProducts() 
{
    global $domainUrl;
    $token = json_decode(getAdminToken(),true);
    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 
    $requestUrl = $domainUrl.'index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=';//get all products
    $ch = curl_init();
    try{
        $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result);

        if(isset($result->message)){
            echo $result->message;
        }else{
            print_r($result);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}

function getProductStock() 
{
    global $domainUrl;
    $token = json_decode(getAdminToken(),true);
    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 
    $requestUrl = $domainUrl.'index.php/rest/V1/stockItems/SO';
    $ch = curl_init();
    try{
        $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result);

        if(isset($result->message)){
            echo $result->message;
        }else{
            print_r($result);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    die("here");
}

function forgetPassword() 
{
    global $domainUrl;
    global $customerEmail;
    $token = getAdminToken();
    $url=$domainUrl . "rest/V1/customers/password?email=".$customerEmail."&template=email_reset&websiteId=1";
    //echo $url;
     $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
     if($result=='true'){

        $response='{
            "status":"true",
            "message":"Password reset link has been sent to your email id"
        }';
        echo $response;
     }
     else{
        $response='{
                "status":"false",
                "message":"This email address is not registered"
            }';
                        echo $response;
    }
}

function createCustomer($token)
{
    global $customerEmail;
    global $customerPassword;
    global $domainUrl;

    $is_irocker_customer=array("attributeCode" => "is_irocker_customer", "value" => 1);
    $sup_brand_name=array("attributeCode" => "sup_brand_name", "value" => 'testtt');
    $sup_model=array("attributeCode" => "sup_model", "value" => 'test33');

    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/customers';
    $data = [
      "customer" => [
        "email" => $customerEmail,
        "firstname" => "Jane",
        "lastname" => "Doe",
        "addresses" => [[
          "defaultShipping" => true,
          "defaultBilling" => true,
          "firstname" => "Jane",
          "lastname" => "Doe",
          "region" => [
            "regionCode" => "NY",
            "region" => "New York",
            "regionId" => 43
          ],
          "postcode" => "10755",
          "street" => ["123 Oak Ave"],
          "city" => "Purchase",
          "telephone" => "512-555-1111",
          "countryId" => "US"
        ]],
        "customAttributes" => [$is_irocker_customer,$sup_brand_name,$sup_model]
      ],
      "password" => $customerPassword
    ];
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization Bearer: ' . $token
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Got customer $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

function getCustomerToken()
{
    global $customerEmail;
    global $customerPassword;
    global $domainUrl;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token';
    $data = [
        "username" => $customerEmail,
        "password" => $customerPassword
    ];
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Got customer token $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

function createQuote($customerToken)
{
    global $domainUrl;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/carts/mine';
    $data = '';
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $customerToken
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Got quote $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

function addToCart($customerToken, $quoteId)
{
    global $domainUrl;
    global $productSku;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items';
    $data = [
      "cartItem" => [
        "sku" => $productSku,
        "qty" => 1,
        "quote_id" => "$quoteId"
      ]
    ];
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $customerToken
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Added to cart $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

function estimateShipping($customerToken)
{
    global $domainUrl;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods';
    $data = [
        "address" => [
          "region" => "New York",
          "region_id" => 43,
          "region_code" => "NY",
          "country_id" => "US",
          "street" => [
            "123 Oak Ave"
            ],
          "postcode" => "10577",
          "city" => "Purchase",
          "firstname" => "Jane",
          "lastname" => "Doe",
          "customer_id" => 4,
          "email" => "youremail@gmail.com",
          "telephone" => "(512) 555-1111",
          "same_as_billing" => 1
      ]
    ];

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $customerToken
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Estimated shipping $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

function setShippingAndBilling($customerToken)
{
    global $domainUrl;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information';
    $data = [
        "addressInformation" => [
            "shipping_address" => [
                "region" => "New York",
                "region_id" => 43,
                "region_code" => "NY",
                "country_id" => "US",
                "street" => [
                    "123 Oak Ave"
                ],
                "postcode" => "10577",
                "city" => "Purchase",
                "firstname" => "Jane",
                "lastname" => "Doe",
                "email" => "youremail@gmail.com",
                "telephone" => "512-555-1111"
            ],
            "billing_address" => [
                "region" => "New York",
                "region_id" => 43,
                "region_code" => "NY",
                "country_id" => "US",
                "street" => [
                    "123 Oak Ave"
                ],
                "postcode" => "10577",
                "city" => "Purchase",
                "firstname" => "Jane",
                "lastname" => "Doe",
                "email" => "youremail@gmail.com",
                "telephone" => "512-555-1111"
            ],
            "shipping_carrier_code" => "flatrate",
            "shipping_method_code" => "flatrate"
        ]
    ];

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $customerToken
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Set billing and shipping $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

function getStripeToken() {
    global $apiKey;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods",
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $apiKey
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
            "type" => "card",
            "card" => array(
                "number" => "4242424242424242",
                "exp_month" => 8,
                "exp_year" => 22,
                "cvc" => "123"
            )
        ])
    ]);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $resData = json_decode($resp,true);
    if($resData && isset($resData['id']))
    {
        return $resData['id'];
    }
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($resp);

    die("here");
}

function sendPaymentInformation($customerToken)
{
    global $domainUrl;
    $url = $domainUrl.'rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information';
    $data = [
        "paymentMethod" => [
            "method" => "stripe_payments",
            "extension_attributes" => [
                "agreement_ids" => ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
            ],
            "additional_data" => [
                "cc_save" => false,
                "cc_stripejs_token" => getStripeToken()
            ]
        ],
        "billing_address" => [
            "email" => "youremail@gmail.com",
            "region" => "New York",
            "region_id" => 43,
            "region_code" => "NY",
            "country_id" => "US",
            "street" => ["123 Oak Ave"],
            "postcode" => "10577",
            "city" => "Purchase",
            "telephone" => "512-555-1111",
            "firstname" => "Jane",
            "lastname" => "Doe"
        ]
    ];

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $customerToken
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Set billing and shipping $response\n"."<br>";
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

$token = getAdminToken();
if ($token === FALSE) { die('Error getting admin token'); }

// $customer = createCustomer($token);
// die("here");
$customerToken = getCustomerToken();
$quoteId = createQuote($customerToken);
$cart = addToCart($customerToken, $quoteId);
$shipping = estimateShipping($customerToken);
$estimate = setShippingAndBilling($customerToken);
$payment = sendPaymentInformation($customerToken);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($payment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working example that uses Stripe and Magento 2 to place an order via the REST API at:

https://github.com/snez/php-magento-api-sandbox